# Change the monitor that AWN shows up on

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu, dock, awn

I'm using Avant Windows Manager and Xubuntu with pure XFCE4. I'm trying to change the monitor that AWN shows up on. I tried changing the primary monitor with Xrandr, but it doesn't seem to want to change the primary monitor with Xubuntu.

Does anyone know how I can do this? If not, does anyone have suggestion on a dock to use that allows for me to change the monitor it shows up on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by clicking around. For some reason AWN was acting fidgety and would only move when I put my mouse on the absolute edge of the bar. Typically, you only have to hold down the mouse button, once you have clicked it, and drag it where you want it.